# Pass const std::function<void()> as parameter in SDL_AddTimer as void*

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to pass a `const std::function<void()> &` as `void *` to SDL_AddTimer, which its 3rd parameter is `void *`.

I tried with reinterpret_cast

```
SDL_AddTimer(interval, wrapper, reinterpret_cast<void *>(const_cast<std::function<void()> *>(fn)));
```

But on my wrapper, it crashes

```
uint32_t wrapper(uint32_t interval, void *param) {
  auto fn = static_cast<std::function<void()> *>(param);
  (*fn)(); // crashes here.
  return interval;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Usage:

```
timer t;
t.set(1000, []() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: where is the `const std::function<void()> &` ? If `fn` is not a pointer then `const_cast<std::function<void()> *>(fn)` makes no sense. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: what is the lifetime of `fn`?  If it goes out of scope you are accessing a dangling pointer.

Comment: I have updated with usage, the fn is supposed to have the same life span of timer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `std::function` into a `void*` like you are doing (you can't even cast a reference into a pointer the way you are doing).

But, you can pass the *address* of the `std::function` object itself. That is what your `wrapper` is expecting anyway, eg:

```
auto &fn_ref = const_cast<std::function<void()> &>(fn); // note & not *
SDL_AddTimer(interval, wrapper, &fn_ref);
```

```
uint32_t wrapper(uint32_t interval, void *param) {
  auto fn = static_cast<std::function<void()> *>(param);
  (*fn)();
  return interval;
}
```

Just make sure the `std::function` object stays alive while the SDL timer is running. However, based on your usage example, it appears the `std::function` object may go out of scope before the timer ever has a chance to call it.  So, you will have to save the `std::function` object somewhere until the timer stops running, eg:

```
class timer {
    SDL_TimerID timerID = 0;
    std::function<void()> timerFunc;

public:
    timer() = default;
    ~timer();

    void set(uint32_t interval, const std::function<void()> &fn);
    void stop();
};
```

```
uint32_t wrapper(uint32_t interval, void *param) {
  auto fn = static_cast<std::function<void()> *>(param);
  (*fn)();
  return interval;
}

timer::~timer() {
    stop();
}

void timer::set(uint32_t interval, const std::function<void()> &fn) {
    stop();
    timerFunc = fn;
    timerID = SDL_AddTimer(interval, wrapper, &timerFunc);
}

void timer::stop() {
    if (timerID != 0) {
        SDL_RemoveTimer(timerID);
        timerID = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly, thank you. One question, can I pass fn as reference or should pass a copy?

Comment: @Rodrigo you will have to pass a copy, as the original `fn` is temporary. I have updated my example to show this.